# Impression event not fired using the Firebase Admob plugin when on a Test Ad?

Tags: admob, flutter

I implemented a banner ad on my Flutter App and everything works fine using the Test Ad except I can't detect the 'impression' event in the listener. Other events like the 'loaded' and 'opened' are detected fine, but not the 'impression' event.

DebugView events on Firebase also does not show the automatically collected events ad_query, ad_impression and ad_exposure. However it does show the ad_click event.

Is this normal behavior for a Test Ad? I'm just making sure before using a real Ad ID.

My code looks like this if it matters, does the retry logic look good?

```
  BannerAd _bannerAd;

  BannerAd createBannerAd() {
    return BannerAd(
      adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
      size: AdSize.smartBanner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        if (event == MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
           // retry loading ad
          _loadAd(); 
          print("Ad Failed to load, retrying");
        }
        if (event == MobileAdEvent.impression) {
          print("Impression");
        }
        print("------BannerAd event :$event");
      },
    );
  }

  _loadAd() async {
    // duration to wait before showing ad
    var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 5);

    return new Timer(_duration, () {
      _bannerAd?.dispose();
      _bannerAd = createBannerAd()..load();
      _bannerAd..show();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
    _bannerAd?.dispose();
    // Run timer to show ad after certain delay
    _loadAd();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bannerAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```